# Requirements for SciPy Bootstrap Wrapper Function

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to use the SciPy `bootstrap` function to work with a simple difference of medians. The following example, from the SciPy documentation, works fine.

```
from scipy.stats import mood, norm

def my_statistic(sample1, sample2, axis):
    statistic, _ = mood(sample1, sample2, axis=-1)
    return statistic

sample1 = norm.rvs(scale=1, size=100)
sample2 = norm.rvs(scale=2, size=100)
data = (sample1, sample2)
res = bootstrap(data, my_statistic, method='basic')
```

However, when I try using a function that computes the difference of medians of two datasets, I get a "ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated" error. Here is the function in question.

```
import numpy as np

def median_diff(group1, group2, axis=-1):
    diff = np.median(group1) - np.median(group2)
    return diff
```

I've tried axis=0, 1 and -1 and that doesn't make any difference. That argument is only there because the [SciPy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.bootstrap.html#scipy.stats.bootstrap) says it's required.

The full error message with traceback is:

```
 ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_259/1837026830.py in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 boot = bootstrap(lab4data, median_diff, method="basic")

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/scipy/stats/_resampling.py in bootstrap(data, statistic, n_resamples, batch, vectorized, paired, axis, confidence_level, method, bootstrap_result, random_state)
    589         # Compute bootstrap distribution of statistic
    590         theta_hat_b.append(statistic(*resampled_data, axis=-1))
--> 591     theta_hat_b = np.concatenate(theta_hat_b, axis=-1)
    592 
    593     # Calculate percentile interval
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py in concatenate(*args, **kwargs)
ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated
```

How does my function need to be different?

Comment: full error message please!

Comment: OK, I added it to the question body.

Comment: The immediate error implies that `theta_hat_b` is a 1d array (or equivalent list) e.g. `np.concatenate(np.arange(10))` produces this error.  But I don't know enough about `bootstrap` to know what that list is, The function [source] is available via the documentation page.  I  can get the same error with the previous `data` and your new function.

Comment: Yes, something about that function is causing the error. The question is what.

Comment: Try adding a debugging print to the `statistic` function to display the shape of the argument arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a diagnostic print to the statistic function:

```
In [57]: def median_diff(group1, group2, axis=-1):
    ...:     diff = np.median(group1) - np.median(group2)
    ...:     print(group1.shape, group2.shape, diff)
    ...:     return diff
    ...: 
    ...:
```

Run with the input `data` list:

```
In [58]: median_diff(*data)
(100,) (100,) -0.5152173131401271
Out[58]: -0.5152173131401271
```

But when run in bootstrap, the `data` is 2d:

```
In [59]: res = bootstrap(data, median_diff, method='basic')
(9999, 100) (9999, 100) -0.46106790632314354
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-073accca9196> in <module>
----> 1 res = bootstrap(data, median_diff, method='basic')

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/stats/_bootstrap.py in bootstrap(data, statistic, vectorized, paired, axis, confidence_level, n_resamples, batch, method, random_state)
    464         # Compute bootstrap distribution of statistic
    465         theta_hat_b.append(statistic(*resampled_data, axis=-1))
--> 466     theta_hat_b = np.concatenate(theta_hat_b, axis=-1)
    467 
    468     # Calculate percentile interval

~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py in concatenate(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated
```

Using the axis parameter:

```
In [61]: def median_diff(group1, group2, axis=-1):
    ...:     diff = np.median(group1, axis) - np.median(group2, axis)
    ...:     print(group1.shape, group2.shape, diff)
    ...:     return diff
    ...:
```

The function now works:

```
In [62]: res = bootstrap(data, median_diff, method='basic')
(9999, 100) (9999, 100) [-0.58497618 -0.73443767 -0.75436132 ... -0.6955514  -0.62782726
 -0.56389115]
(100,) (100,) -0.5152173131401271
```

We got the `concatenate` error because the function returned a scalar, when `bootstrap` was expecting an array (of shape (9999,).

Comment: Thank you! I hope they make the documentation clearer on this point.